# NO PUB_KEY AVAILABLE

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, update-manager

whenever i try to get updates i keep getting this error below
please how do i resolve this issue . i have tried all i know my current OS version is ubuntu 23.04 lunar lobster

```
sudo apt-get update
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23E7166788B63E1E
Hit:9 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                        
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates/main amd64 Packages [503 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [81.3 kB]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lunar-security/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/yarn.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
```